# Stateful long living android service

Tags: android

I am trying to implement something like scrobbler (the app which retrieves current playing song metadata and write it to database on my server).

So I have a service like that

```
public class ListenerService extends Service {

    private static final int SCROBBLE_TIME_PERIOD = 30000;

    private Song currentSong;
    private Date startListeningTime;

    public ListenerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        //Google Android player
        filter.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
        filter.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
        filter.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Song song = new Song(intent.getStringExtra("artist"), intent.getStringExtra("album"),
                    intent.getStringExtra("track"));

            if (!currentSong.equals(song)) {
                currentSong = song;
                startListeningTime = new Date();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - startListeningTime.getTime() >= SCROBBLE_TIME_PERIOD) {
            ///... write song to db
            currentSong = null;
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In `onCreate()` method I register reciever. The reciver just update current playing song variable and set time when playing was started.

I want to call periodically `onStartCommand()` method which just checks that current song is playing more than 30 seconds and writting it to database.
I google it, but all examples show how to create a new service periodically when I want to call onStartCommand of existing service (just send new intent to it).
Is there any way to do it?

UPD.
In another post I read that in android it is impossible to make service live forever (while the phone is on). So when android kill my service, I will lose info from `currentSong` and `startListeningTime` variables. Should I store this sort of information in some other place (where?) or there is some working way to prevent service from force closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your service type based on returning value in onStartCommand.
 If you return `START_NOT_STICKY`, whenever service is killed, it won't be created again.
If you return `START_STICKY`, whenever service is killed, it will be created again from OS. But be careful, intent will be null in this case.
If you return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, whenever service is killed, it will be created with last intent which service created before.
Checkout this link to learn more about service at background
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

```
Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - startListeningTime.getTime() >= SCROBBLE_TIME_PERIOD) {
            ///... write song to db
            currentSong = null;
        }
        return START_STICKY;//if you write START_STICKY service will always stay at background.
    }
```

> UPD. In another post I read that in android it is impossible to make service live forever (while the phone is on). So when android kill my service, I will lose info from currentSong and startListeningTime variables. Should I store this sort of information in some other place (where?) or there is some working way to prevent service from force closing?

You can store all information into internal storage or database. You can use SharedPreferences if you store only basic types(or you can use GSON to store complex type into it).
In this application you might use Alarm Manager if you have periodic jobs, and start your service at 30 secs.

OnStartCommand is called everytime you run startService method. So you are not creating a new service, you are sending an intent to it.

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you.

Comment: Will Alarm Manager initiate onStartCommand method or some else? Can you give some good example of using Alarm Manager in whis way please? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can checkout this, https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html . Official document from google, create a broadcast receiver to handle intent, start your service inside your intent and you are good to go